# Trouble running a simple "Hello world" using Visual Studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've recently started to learn C++ however I can't even get a simple program to even **run**. I am using Visual Studio Code and I used this tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw to set up C++. I followed every step and have not gotten any errors even until this point. Whenever I try to run helloworld.exe from the terminal in Visual Studio Code, nothing happens, not even any errors show up. Please help!

(Side question: Every time I want to run an updated version of my code, do I have to build it before running it using Ctrl+Shift+B? Also, do you have to run code through the terminal? Is there no easy to press run button or shortcut like in PyCharm for Python to run code?)
[image]

Here is a picture of my tasks.json:
[image]

Comment: We get loads of beginners here struggling  with VS Code. In my view it's not suitable for beginners. You don't say anything about your platform but my advice would be to pick a different IDE.

Comment: You've tagged your question with Visual C++. Visual C++ and VS Code are completely different products.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63290694/edit) and paste in the code and config script as text. Text is much easier to search and images are an impossible barrier to too many users for a wide variety of reasons. Usually all a picture is good for is chumming for downvotes.

Comment: And to answer your other question, no you don't have to run C++ through the terminal. But obviously the details differ depending on the IDE you have picked.

Comment: I suggest [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) as an alternative.

Comment: There's no "Visual Studio Code 2019". Only Visual Studio (no "code") uses year numbers as versions.

Comment: Try running the `helloworld.exe` by double-clicking it in the explorer (instead of from the terminal). You might get a proper error message that way.

Comment: True, but only until Microsoft decides to go back to using version numbers and skips one because marketing wants to "catch up" with Apple.

Comment: You are on Windows. I agree with Eljay, get yourself Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: Keep in mind that Visual Studio (unlike Visual Studio Code) is not cross-platform. It's a nice IDE, sure, but it binds you to Windows.

Comment: C++ programs are not called scripts, by the way.

Comment: My crystal ball says your compiler `bin` directory is not in the `PATH`, and it contains some `.dll`s your compiled programs need to work. Possible options are: (pick one) 1. Add `"-static"` to the compiler flags (after line 12 in the config) to make your programs not depend on the `.dll`s, 2. Add the compiler `bin` directory to the `PATH`. 3. Copy the necessary `.dll`s from the compiler `bin` directory to where `helloworld.exe` is. To know what dlls are needed, run your program by double-clicking it in the explorer, then you should get a error message with a name of the missing dll.

Comment: *"Every time I want to run an updated version of my code, do I have to build it before running it using Ctrl+Shift+B?"* Well, when was the last time you actually compiled that program? Was it as showed in the picture?

Comment: Force a new use to learn json so they can hack `tasks.json` just to learn C++? I second what @john suggested, but I will go even farther. Pick an *Editor*, and pick your favorite shell (on windows, either `cmd.exe` or PowerShell). Then simply compile from the command line invoking the compiler and linker you have installed. You can compile whatever file you want, instantly, without the need to monkey with a Project, etc.. Further, you learn how to use the compiler so you can later tell whatever IDE you use how you want it done (instead of the other way around)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you open the terminal and go to your folder using cd and the folder name, and compile the file with:

```
g++ filename.cpp
```

and run it with:

```
./a.out
```

For Unix systems for windows I think it is:

```
./a.exe
```